# How to make FactoryBot return the right STI sub class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm making a big change in my system, so I changed one of my main tables into a STI, and create subclasses to implement the specific behavior.

```rb
class MainProcess < ApplicationRecord
end

class ProcessA < MainProcess
end

class ProcessB < MainProcess
end
```

In the application code, if I run `MainProcess.new(type: 'ProcessA')` it will return a **ProcessA** as I want.
But in the Rspec tests when I run `FactoryBot::create(:main_process, type: 'ProcessA')` it is returning a **MainProcess** and breaking my tests.

My factor is something like this

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :main_process do
    foo { 'bar' }
  end

  factory :process_a, parent: :main_process, class: 'ProcessA' do
  end

  factory :process_b, parent: :main_process, class: 'ProcessB' do
  end
end
```

Is there some way to make FactoryBot have the same behavior of normal program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :main_process do
    initialize_with do
      klass = type.constantize
      klass.new(attributes)  
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

The answer was founded here http://indigolain.hatenablog.com/entry/defining-factory-for-sti-defined-model (in japanese)

###### Edit #1:

##### ⚠⚠⚠ Important ⚠⚠⚠

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72409948/2180456) `initialize_with` is part of a private FactoryBot API.

According to the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/FactoryBot%2FConfiguration:initialize_with):

> This method is part of a private API. You should avoid using this method if possible, as it may be removed or be changed in the future.

So avoid to use if you can. (although I didn't find any other way to achieve this result without use it)

###### Edit #2

Besides the warning in the gem documentation (described above), the [GETTING_STARTED.md](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction) actually suggest you use it

> If you want to use factory_bot to construct an object where some attributes are passed to initialize or if you want to do something other than simply calling new on your build class, you can override the default behavior by defining initialize_with on your factory

Comment: Brilliant! I've been looking for a way to have my subclass instances be wrapped in traits, and this was the solution to do it.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me in factory_bot 6.1, rspec-core 3.10, and rspec-rails 5.0.1. While @Jared's solution below **really should work** per the FactoryBot documentation, apparently it doesn't currently with STI. :(

Answer (score 3):

`initialize_with` is marked as part of FactoryBot's Private API and not recommended for external use.

I think you can use nested factories to accomplish this.

```
  factory :process do

    factory :type_a_process, class: Process::TypeA do
      type {"Process::TypeA"}
    end

    factory :type_b_process, class: Process::TypeB do
      type {"Process::TypeB"}
    end

  end
end

FactoryBot.create(:type_b_process)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a note about your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you just modify your original code to specify the class as the class type instead of a string, it works:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :main_process do
    foo { 'bar' }
  end

  factory :process_a, parent: :main_process, class: ProcessA do
  end

  factory :process_b, parent: :main_process, class: ProcessB do
  end
end
```

Here's the [relevant section of the FactoryBot documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#defining-factories).

Comment: This seemed to work at first for me. However, when I tried `a = build(:process_a); a.class` I got what was expected: `class ProcessA < MainProcess`, **but** `a.instance_of?(ProcessA)` I got false, and could no longer run `a.reload`. For some reason, @Alan Alves de Oliveira's answer worked. Running factory_bot 6.1, rspec-core 3.10, and rspec-rails 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

initialize_with { type.present? ? type.constantize.new : Invoice.new }

https://dev.to/epigene/simple-trick-to-make-factorybot-work-with-sti-j09